# Files aren't showing up in windows bash

Tags: windows, bash

I just set up bash for windows with the new windows update. After setting up a username and password and trying to navigate through my directories I find that there is nothing there. Does anyone know why this happened and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by nothing is there? Do "cd /" and try "ls" here to see if there are files here. Your other drives are mounted in '/mnt/". In case nothing works, reinstall WSL. Run the following  in an elevated command prompt.

```
lxrun /uninstall /full
lxrun /install
```

And properly answer the questions.

Comment: Of course I checked in my home directory, but there is nothing there.Furthermore, lxrun command is not found

Comment: run lxrun in windows command promt, not bash. If it isn't found here, run sfc (your system is screwed)

Answer (score 0):

By default, it puts you in your `home` directory.  There is nothing in it.

Type `ls /` to see if there are folders in the root.  I would bet there are.